# How do I make an if statement goto a point when a certain input is entered? Microsoft Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, if-statement, readline, goto

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in C#. I have made a program that asks a series of questions, at the end, it asks if there is any mistakes. How can i make it so that if the user enters "No", it does "goto" to a certain point? this what i have so far.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Is This Correct? Yes/No");
        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        if (response = No)
        goto Loop;
```

As this does not work, Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does it not work exactly? What errors are you getting, when?

Comment: Do you have a label in your code named `Loop`?

Comment: If you feel like this is the answer you were looking for, marking it as answered with help with your answered ratio (and getting help in the future).

Answer (score 5):

```
string Response = "No";
while (Response != "Yes")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loop");
    Console.WriteLine("Is This Correct? Yes/No");
    Response = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I made a modification on that, and now it works. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` statement is incorrect.  `No` shoud be a string.  Try this:

```
if (response == "No")
```

Comment: +1 as likely, but since whole bunch of code is missing in the sample there very well could be `String No="Yes";`